# How To Handle Time Ambiguity Caused by Daylight Saving Time Clock Rollback

Tags: java, datetime, dst

I have this scenario that I would like to see if there is a better solution: 
I receive a timestamp from system A, in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", without timezone but they can fix it to be UTC. 
And then I need to SSH into system B to get a "last sync time", which could be in the past, and it does not return any time zone, not even the year (from a backup product), and here is an example: 
"Sync'ed-as-of time:  Sun Nov  3 01:13" 
System B is a backup appliance that runs some proprietary software, and there is an internal scheduler which wakes up every 15 minutes to check if there is any data that need to be synced from the source. If the previous sync is still running, it will let the current one finish without taking further action. This "last sync time" will be updated after each sync, so it should not lag behind the current system time more than a couple of hours in the worst scenario. 
I need to compare these two timestamps to make sure "last sync time" on B is later than A. If not I need to wait and retry the query until B is later than A to proceed to the next step. 
I have the java program sitting on a Linux box that when request coming in from A, it queries B for the "last sync time", and after that immediately issues a "date" command to B to get the current system time, which returns the current system time in the format of "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", e.g.,  
"Fri Jun 14 21:07:07 EDT 2019",  
so the program can apply the year, and the timezone of this output to complete the timestamp of the "last sync time". The program does handle the case the "last snync time" and "date" output are spread across a year boundary. 
It works fine except when the summer daylight savings time ends, and clock rolls back (2am back to 1am ), there is an one hour window the time will be ambiguous: 
For example, I get a 1:20am timestmap from system A (converted from UTC already to local), and then when I get a 1:30am from system B, I cannot tell if B is later than A. It could be the 1:30 before the clock change. The current timezone of system B, does not clarify which timezone the "last sync time" was in. 
We asked the user to switch all of the systems to UTC time, so we do not need to worry about the clock adjustment. But that has too much impact to the environment. 
One alternative is that I handle that one hour specially and wait until the "last sync time" timestamp goes beyond 2am. To do that I will need to check in the code whether this is the specific hour every time I do the timestamp comparison, which I think is not optimal. But I cannot think of a better way. 
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. And if this is the way to go, is there a good Java library to figure out the day light saving switching date? Thanks a million!

Comment: You can send a "heart beat" request to System B and ask for their last sync time. Keep a cache of this last sync time. When the time is brought back from 2AM to 1AM - you will run into a situation when the new last sync time will be before the cached last sync time. This way you will know when System B has changed its time. How often you send the "heart beat" request is up to you but at least once an hour (avoid times around the hour mark to account for send and receive delays) is necessary for this mechanism to work.

Comment: My program is not running as a daemon. It only gets triggered when the request from system A comes in. And this last sync time depends on how much data has been replicated so it is not updated in a completely predicable fashion. Keep a cache seems quite a complicated change to the design...

Comment: You should also only do this timestamp comparison once. You should not perform the comparison more than once. You should instead wrap this logic into a class and pass the object to where you need it. This way you wont run into problems like "check in the code whether this is the specific hour every time I do the timestamp comparison"

Comment: You would only have to cache 1 number - the previous time stamp.

Comment: Hmm, so for that one hour of the year, now I have to write a daemon to query and record a timestamp every hour? And make sure this code is functioning all the time? Is it just easier to check if it is that special hour and delay the query until the last sync time on system B passes that one hour?

Comment: What *exactly* do you get in the response from system B?  A particular string? A numeric timestamp?  Are you looking at the direct response or some intermediate object?  Please provide an example.

Comment: Also, can you be assured that the "sync" happens regularly enough to make assumptions that the time you get is even on the same date? Or if you decide to wait until after the ambiguity period, are you assured that it will indeed run again?  How do you know that? What happens if it doesn't?

Comment: Here is a sample response from system B: "Sync'ed-as-of time:   Sun Nov  3 01:13". Sync is running on system B with an internal scheduler, that checks every 15 min, so I would say regularly. But if the previous sync takes longer than 15 min, it will not do anything until that finishes, so it can take from a few min to a few hours, but usually won't run over a day.

Comment: Regarding "is there a good Java library..." - Modern Java code should be using the `java.time` package, which has been built-in since Java 8.  [`ZoneRules.getValidOffsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getValidOffsets-java.time.LocalDateTime-) will tell you the offsets that apply for a given `LocalDateTime` in a particular time zone.  If more than one offset is returned, you're in an ambiguous period.

Comment: And how do you know the time zone of system B? Or are you assuming it is the same as the time zone you're running the code from? Keep in mind that DST happens at different dates and times (or not at all) depending on the time zone.

Comment: I probably did not explain it very clear: I run a query right after I query the last sync time to get the current system time on B, to derive the year and the timezone for last sync time. That can cross the year boundary if the timing is right so I had to handle that...

Comment: Unless *that* query gives you more detail than you just showed, you won't be able to derive the time zone by such a mechanism.  You could only derive the offset from UTC. (See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).)  This matters due to what I said in my last comment - DST is not uniform worldwide.  Even if you are limiting your results to a single country, you can't necessarily assume anything about DST or time zones.

Comment: For example, in the US, Hawaii and most of Arizona do not presently have DST.  You also don't know if DST will be cancelled or made permanent by future legislation (which is a real possibility in some US states given laws recently passed in Washington, Oregon, and Florida, and pending in California).

Outside of the US, the European Union is planning big changes in 2020, and other countries do strange things (like an island near Australia that only advances by 30 minutes instead of the 1 hour).

Comment: Hi, Matt, thanks for all the response. Really appreciate that. But you get me confused now. I send a query to get the last sync time, and immediately followed with a command "date" to get the time of the same system, so in the worst case, I get, say EST, instead of EDT, which the last sync time was supposed to be in, will the java library zonerule work?

Comment: Sorry, but you're not providing enough detail... what do you mean exactly by "followed with a command 'date'"?  You mean you're running arbitrary commands on a Linux Bash or Windows command shell? Or some kind of RPC? Or a SOAP or REST API?  These details should be in the question.  It's also not clear what you mean by "I get say EST instead of EDT" do you mean you get a string with those characters in it?  If so, are you aware that these could be ambiguous? ("CST" could be "Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time", "China Standard Time", etc.)

Comment: At this point, I'm voting to close the question as "too broad".  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Then search, and ask a new (smaller, targeted) question if you need to. Good luck.

Comment: I updated the post based on your suggestion. was trying not to bore the readers with all the details but I guess I assumed too many things in mind. "EDT" is East Daylight Saving Time and EST is "East Standard Time" for East Coast United States. Sorry I am mostly in the Linux world.

Comment: @LibbyShen `EST`/`EDT` are not [true time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Real time zones come in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/New_York` or `America/Montreal`.  These 2-4 letter codes are pseudo-zones. They are *not* standardized, and are *not* even unique! While `EST` might mean east coast US time to you, it may have a different meaning elsewhere. For example, to you `CST` might mean central time in much of North America, but to a billion other people it means “China Standard Time”. This has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: You are working with some badly designed systems. This Question is a great example of why programmers should be working/storing/exchanging moments in UTC generally, and should be using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats to write moments as text. If your code does not run reliably often enough (less than an hour between all calls), there is no way to fix the ambiguity of your mystery hour without guessing, as discussed above. So I too am voting to close this as too broad. Changing these systems to emit UTC in ISO 8601 fixes all your problems.

Comment: @BasilBourque I edited the original post one more time, hopefully to clarify the use case. The last sync time on system B won't lag behind more than a few hours of the current time, so I believe the solution Ole V.V. provided below works fine. I tested with different time zones and saw the desirable results. I agree the systems are poorly designed, except it is an actual use case that I have to deal with right now. I am unfortunately to be stuck with legacy systems and CLI outputs that I cannot change. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no way that you can be completely sure. “Sun Nov 3” might be in 2002, 2013 or 2019 or even further back in history. One way would be if you can assume that the last sync time is not more than, say, a few years before the current system B system time that you get (and also not *after* that time), and report an error if you can detect that it is not within those few years.

The trick when summer time (daylight saving time) ends is always to assume the earlier time if there is any ambiguity. In this way when you detect that sync time is later than the timestamp from A, this is true no matter how the ambiguous sync time is interpreted. It also implies that you will wait until the last sync time goes after 2 AM as you suggested. I wouldn’t expect this to be prohibitively expensive in terms of comparison, but if you need to be sure, you need to make your own measurements and judgement.

```
    final DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    final ZoneId systemBTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    final String syncFormatPattern = "'Sync''ed-as-of time:' EEE MMM d HH:mm";
    final DateTimeFormatter currentSystemBTiemFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Collections.singleton(systemBTimeZone))
            .appendPattern(" yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);
    final Period maxSyncAge = Period.ofYears(2);

    String systemATimestampString = "2019-11-03-06-05-55";
    String lastSyncMsg = "Sync'ed-as-of time: Sun Nov 3 01:13";
    String currentSystemBTime = "Sun Nov 03 01:13:07 EDT 2019";
    OffsetDateTime systemATimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(systemATimestampString, timestampFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ZonedDateTime maxLastSyncTime
            = ZonedDateTime.parse(currentSystemBTime, currentSystemBTiemFormatter);
    ZonedDateTime minLatSyncTime = maxLastSyncTime.minus(maxSyncAge);
    int candidateYear = maxLastSyncTime.getYear();
    ZonedDateTime syncTime;
    while (true) {
        DateTimeFormatter syncFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern(syncFormatPattern)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, candidateYear)
                .toFormatter(Locale.US);
        try {
            syncTime = LocalDateTime.parse(lastSyncMsg, syncFormatter)
                    .atZone(systemBTimeZone)
                    .withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
            if (syncTime.isBefore(minLatSyncTime) || syncTime.isAfter(maxLastSyncTime)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Last sync time is out of range");
            }
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            // Ignore; try next earlier year
        }
        candidateYear--;
    }
    System.out.println("Last sync time: " + syncTime);
    System.out.println("Timestamp from system A: " + systemATimestamp);
    System.out.println("Is OK? " + syncTime.toOffsetDateTime().isAfter(systemATimestamp));
```

As the snippet stands, the output from it is:

> ```
> Last sync time: 2019-11-03T01:13-04:00[America/New_York]
> Timestamp from system A: 2019-11-03T06:05:55Z
> Is OK? false
> ```

You can see that it has chosen to interpret the last sync time of 01:13 as daylight time, the offset is -04:00, which causes the check to fail. The time might also have been in standard time, offset -05:00, in which case the UTC equivalent would have been 06:13, and the check would have succeeded. But as discussed, to be on the safe side, we prefer wait until the sync time goes after 02:00 and gets unambiguous again.

The while loop keeps parsing the string assuming different years until it hits a year where the day of week matches.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this code. It is greatly appreciated. There is an internal scheduler on system B to wait up and sync every 15 minutes, and update the "last sync time". But if the previous sync is still going on, it will skip the current one. Depends on how much data to sync, it could take from 0 minute to a few hours, but it should not go beyond a couple of years. It could be in the last year if it happens right at the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Got this in the comment from Matt Johnson which I believe is the best solution:

*Modern Java code should be using the java.time package, which has been built-in since Java 8. ZoneRules.getValidOffsets will tell you the offsets that apply for a given LocalDateTime in a particular time zone. If more than one offset is returned, you're in an ambiguous period.*